# Repeating content on the same page for "emphasis"

Tags: html, accessibility, usability

I am working on a government website that must meet Section 508 ADA standards.

A request was made by one of our customers to emphasize a certain piece of content by placing it in two areas of the homepage: Within a slideshow, as well as inside a box underneath this slideshow.

Would this be considered a violation of ADA standards or at least, usability practices?

Answer (score 1):

A lot more context is needed to be able to answer this well. Some factors to consider:

- Is the text exactly the same?
- Are you repeating it with text or via an image?
- Is it obvious from context that the text is redundant (to prevent a screen reader user from assuming she has jumped back up the page)?
- Is this text actionable (is it a link or a button or part of a call to action)?
- How close to other text is it in the DOM?

If the content exists within a slide show / carousel (and you offer a method to skip the carousel), then I understand there may be a valid use case to present the information a second time. You may have analytics that support this (few users in my own tests make it to the second or third slide).

If the content is exactly the same but clearly distinct and will not cause confusion for screen reader users (so they do not feel they are repeating the page), you should be good. For non-SR users I cannot think of an issue outside of things that would fail anyway (keyboard traps, context, complex writing, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in repeating text for accessibility (for SEO it might not be a good choice as it could be considered as keyword spoofing).

However **you may consider using `aria-hidden` on one of the occurence** in order for screenreaders not to read it twice.